# Get Category and Excerpt From wp_get_recent_posts

Tags: functions

I'm using the function `wp_get_recent_posts` to return the latest three posts on a page and I want to get them with their titles, categories, and a brief excerpt.  When I look at the documentation on that function, I see that it returns an array of items, but it doesn't say what is available in that array to extract from, so I'm testing by guessing at the names ([see this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts)) - my guess on the post_content was right.

For getting the category, I've tried `$recent["category"]`, `$recent["the_category"]`, and `$recent["post_category"]` and for the excerpt I've tried those as well, except replace category with excerpt.  The code I'm using is below:

```
<?php
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
                    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

                        echo '<h2><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a></h2><h3>Posted in '. $recent["the_category"] .'</h3><p>'.$recent["post_content"].'</p>';


                    }
                    wp_reset_query();
                ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `WP_Query()` instead. Like so:

```
<?php
$category = 'whatever';
$new_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'category_name'     => $category;
    )
);

if ($new_query->have_posts()) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($new_query->have_posts()) {
        $new_query->the_post();
        $postid = get_the_ID();
        // Your output code.
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Merely change `$category` to whatever you need. Make it an array() if you want to have several categories.
If however, you will be doing this for a custom post type, you need to use the `tax_query` array, like so:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'people',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'bob',
    ),
),
```

Above example is taken straight from the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: So with this function, I can filter by category?  Reading documentation, looks like `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'staff' ) );`?

Comment: @WashDCDev Yes that would work. If you use it for custom post type however, you'd need to use 'tax_query' which is a bit more complicated, but still easy imho. I'll amend my answer to include the category filtering.

Comment: @WashDCDev I have amended my answer with both the category and tax_query code.

Comment: Cool; excellent answer.